# Generating GeoJSON tiles from GeoDjango - basic overview?

Tags: tiles, geodjango, geojson

I'm working with the glorious PolyMaps and I want to build a map similar to the [population example](http://polymaps.org/ex/population.html).

I understand that this needs GeoJSON tiles. I have a GeoDjango database, with a bunch of County objects, each of which has a Polygon field - these are what I'd like to display on the map.

Can anyone give me a high-level overview of how to turn these County polygons into GeoJSON tiles?

I've seen [this question recommending TileStache](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3712/create-vector-geojson-tiles-for-polymaps), but is TileStache the most sensible thing to use with GeoDjango? And if so, how would TileStache fit in?

Bonus points for explaining what a GeoJSON tile, um, *is*.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I've made it work following [this tutorial](http://www.itopen.it/2012/01/09/tilestache-django-tiny-wrapper/).

*Edit :*

One thing that might not be obvious in the link is that you need a `get_config` function that looks like this :

```py
_config = TileStache.Config.buildConfiguration(my_config_dictionary)
def get_config():
    return _config
```

where `my_config_dictionary` is a TileStache config dictionary like in the [TileStache's doc](http://tilestache.org/doc/#vector-provider) that makes the link with your database.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer... then your likely to get more up-votes.

Comment: I added some details but I don't see how I can add more without copy pasting the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If your data isn't too big it may be easier to just serve the data as geojson objects.
Where your django "MyFeature" Model has a poly (PolygonField) object.

If you data is bigger it makes sense to for you to use a map server to tilize your data as png tiles and serve them as a map layer.  I'm still trying to figure this part out myself.

```
def get_layer_data(request, layer_id=None):
    """
    Return the features for the given bbox (bounding box) as a list of geojson objects.
    /layers/<id>/?bbox=<lon1>,<lat1>,<lon2>,<lat2>
    """
    bbox_raw = request.GET.get("bbox", None)
    bbox = None

    if bbox_raw and bbox_raw.count(",") == 3:        
        bbox = [float(v) for v in bbox_raw.split(",")]     
    if not bbox:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Improperly formed or not given 'bbox' option, should be in the format 'bbox=lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2'")

    bbox_poly = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)    
    features = MyFeature.objects.filter(poly__centroid__within=bbox_poly, layer=layer_id)

    # build vector polygons from bin
    data = []
    for feature in features:
        geojson = feature.poly.geojson
        data.append(json.loads(geojson)) # convert to dict so whole list can be converted to json
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json') 
    return response
```