# GeoJSON in Leaflet TileLayer?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm just starting to work with leaflet and have a basic question about showing a geoJSON file. First, I found this excellent article with example code:

http://bl.ocks.org/lxbarth/4019660

However I have a more basic/beginner question, in that example the set the JSON file through this url:

http://polymaps.appspot.com/county/{z}/{x}/{y}.json

However, the file I converted (from shapefile to geojson using quantum gis) is just a .geojson extension. I'm clearly missing something here, perhaps a way to convert the geojson file into a tile format? Can someone elaborate as to how I'm supposed to do this or what my missing step is? Do I need to be hosting the geoJSON file on a server in order to do this?

If my file is called polygons.geojson, how would I go about using it in the above reference code? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're looking for? Is your geojson layer overlaying a base map such as OpenStreetMap? If so, make sure your layer is saved with projection 4326(WGS84) You can store you're layer within your file structure. Check out these references: [leaflet-ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) and this [leaflet tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html)

Comment: Yes, my goal is to overlay municipality areas over an OSM basemap in Leaflet. I'm doing almost the same exact thing in this link: http://bl.ocks.org/lxbarth/4019660           Except my file is called "areas.geojson" but in that example they set the geojson file with a url that ends in "county/{z}/{x}/{y}.json"  It appears as though they want XYZ coordinates and not a file name there.. I'm unsure as to how to set the path correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I guess your question is a bit confused because you mixed 2 notions which are not necessarily associated. To be clear :

- on one part, you can read and display geojson files with leaflet (**geojson is a format**). Following this URL, you will find basics examples : http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html
- on the other part, leaflet is also able to understand and display tiles through the [TileLayer object](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer). **Tiles are a way to optimize the map rendering** (independently of the format).

On the given example, the map displays geojson polymaps tiles, mixing both geojson format and tiles mechanism.

According to your needs you can choose to :

1. display the full geojson file (easy to implement, ok for small size files),
2. create your own tiles with [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/doc/TileStache.Goodies.Providers.PostGeoJSON.html). Regarding geojson tiles creation a question was asked before, you may [refer to the accepted answer and given links](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3712/create-vector-tiles-for-polymaps).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Indeed, my question was confused, I was unclear if there is a relationship between GeoJSON and tiles. I had seen on several sites references to a "GeoJSON tiles" & based on the url in the sample I thought this may be necessary. I assume creating tiles from GeoJOSN is a vector to raster conversion? Does the "{z}/{x}/{y}.json" indicate a tile conversion has taken place? I just don't understand the naming convention.. my file is called "areas.geojson" but the example says "{z}/{x}/{y}.json". How do I correctly indicate my file name when it is looking for coordinates?

Comment: Geojson is a vector format and there is no raster conversion. Regarding x, y, z you find more information on [the given link, see URL template section](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-l.tilelayer) : *{z} — zoom level, {x} and {y} — tile coordinates*. See also that in [this example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson-example.html), the geojson file is called globally without tiles. If you want to go for a simple solution, just call your *areas.geojson* file.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work after realizing the data was in fact in state plane and the code I had was working perfectly fine.. just had to reproject the data.